# How to make a matrix for a particular surface plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, surface

I have a time column vector

```
t = 
    [0; 
     1; 
     3; 
     7; 
     10]
```

a frequency column vector

```
f = 
    [978;
     573; 
     269; 
     102; 
      14]
```

and an impedance column vector

```
Z = 
    [0; 
     10; 
     64; 
     97; 
     103]
```

The kind of surface plot I'm looking for would be so that if you rotate the figure to display Z vs. t, you would see something equivalent to

```
plot(t, Z)
```

and if you rotate the figure to display Z vs. f, you would see something equivalent to

```
semilogx(f, Z)
```

x axis time, y axis frequency, and z axis impedance.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Zimp1 = flipud(toeplitz(flip(Z)));
figure(1);
surf(t, f, Zimp1);
set(gca, 'Yscale', 'log');
```

The problem lies within the Zimp1 matrix--the matrix that shows what's going on in the surface plot with the values of frequency and time. How do I construct the Zimp1 matrix to give me exactly that: plot(t, Z) on the view([-90, 0]) side and semilogx(f, Z) on the view([0, 0]) side?